# Data binding not working correctly for application on network drive

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, network-drive

I have an application, stored on a network drive, that grabs a template Excel spreadsheet and Word document from a network drive and copies and renames them for a specific site the user enters.

In case the location of these templates or the template names changes, I also have a form within the application from which a user can update the details of the templates. I can include more code, but basically if the user is happy with the changes, the string is stored as follows:

```
 My.Settings.String6 = PermExcelTemp  'PermExcelTemp is a string containing the updated template name for the excel spreadsheet
```

If the application is closed, and run again by the same user who made the change, the updated template name has remained as a permanent change on their application as expected. However, if a different user runs the application, no change is evident and the application throws an error as the template cannot be found, as it is working off old information.

To save having to ask every user to apply the changes to the application, does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? I presumed that as the application is on a network drive, a permanent change like this would apply to all users who run the application.

Comment: User settings are per user.  Where the app/exe is doesnt matter.

Comment: Is there anyway of updating a setting for all users? Or would I have to build the app again from visual studio with the update and place it on the network drive again?